# vim treat '-' as part of a word if it is followed by a letter, but '>'

Tags: vim

Is there a way to tell vim to treat `this-is-one-word` but `this->` the `-` isn't part of the word (when doing `dw` for example).

Edit for clarification:

I have - set to be part of a word, so doing `dw` at the start of `this-is-one-word` deletes all of that. However, if I have the code `$logger->info` and point my cursor at logger then hit `dw` it includes the - which leaves `$>info` instead of `$->info` which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand your question correctly, `dw` only deletes `this` for string `this-is-one-word`

in general if I want to delete `this-is-one-word`, I would use `dt<space>` assuming there is a `<space>` after

Answer (score 0):

Read on `:h iskeyword`. But I guess it is not possible to achieve what you want. Anyway, at least you have a start point:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=-
```

Note: The help says it is local to buffer, that's why `setlocal` in opposition to `set`.

This should be placed at `/after/ftplugin/css.vim` for example, this way the character `-` will be part of the word only in that particular filetype.

In [this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/when-to-use-the-after-directory) you can read about differences between `/ftplugin` and `/after/ftplugin`.